# Create an embed message on DiscordJS 13 with Node JS 16 - Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How to display the latency of the api, and the bot in an embed message on discordJS with node js 16
Expected result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OElZY.png (all in an embed message like this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ4NR.png

I've been trying different things for more than a week, this project is giving me a headache, I've spent my time fixing problems, modifying, deleting, starting again, I'm coming here in the hope to see an END to this command x)

Here is what I have working now : https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Qtg.png
If need be I show you what I tried but it's not ultra necessary, thanks in advance to all those who could help me!

I checked the guide https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor but it didn't help me more to create an embed, I know how to get the data for the latency, but I can't create the embed actually

```
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",


    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send({ content: "Pong." });
    },
};
```

When i do : !ping https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNtNH.png

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to create a simple embed, you can do that like so:

```js
// const Discord = require('discord.js');
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor('author name',  /* avatar */'https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png', '')
    .setDescription('description')
    .setTitle('title')
    .addField('1', 'field 1')
    .addField('2', 'field 2', /* inline */ true)
    .addField('3', 'field 3', /* inline */ true)
channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
```

Result:

[image: The resulting embed]

Don't forget the `[]`! `channel.send()` expects an object that has at least a `content` property of type `string`, or an `embeds` property of type `Discord.MessageEmbed[]`.

See also the discord.js 13 documentation for info on more things you can add to an embed, like a footer for instance. There's also  https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/, which is a useful tool for building embeds, albeit in json.

Comment: Also, regarding https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/, although there is an option to have it generate the code for the embed, the code it generates won't work in discord.js 13—at least the code it generates for _sending_ the embed won't.